# How to deal with skewed distributions with DNNs?

Tags: deep-learning, skewness, naive-bayes

Suppose I have skewed distributions of classes in train set.

How should I deal with it? Just train and network will deal itself? Or some methods are good?

For example, can I artificially make distribution uniform, then train my network and then apply some bayessian methods to take probabilities into account?

**UPDATE**

Distributions of classes is following:

[image]

This is from [`Planet: Understanding the Amazon from Space` competition on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space). Plot is from [this kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/ekami66/step-by-step-solution-with-keras-0-91-on-lb). Multilayered convolutional network is used.

Comment: By skewed distributions did you mean class imbalance? I'm weak with terminology.

Comment: @papabiceps yes, sorry, I am weak in terms too; some classes are very often and anoter ones are very rare...

Comment: What kind of neural network are planning to use and what kind of data are you trying to classify?Do you have any training algorithm in mind ? And how skewed is your dataset can you tell us the proportions like 95% of positive class and 5% negative class.

Comment: @papabiceps see my update please